# Z Boson Decay Width Calculation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, scattering

The graph for a Z boson decay will look something like the following.

[image: Z Boson Decay]

I found that the coupling between an electron and the boson is

$$\frac{ g_2\gamma^{\mu}}{2\cos{\theta_W}}((2\sin^2{\theta_W}-\frac{1}{2}) +\frac{1}{2}\gamma^5).$$

Where $g_2$ is just some constant and $\theta_{W}$ is the Weinberg angle. The expression for the graph is

$$\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{M} = \bar{u}^r(k)\frac{ g_2}{2\cos{\theta_W}}\gamma^{\mu}((2\sin^2{\theta_W}-\frac{1}{2}) +\frac{1}{2}\gamma^5)v^{r'}(k').
\end{equation*}$$

Where $\bar{u}$ denotes an exiting electron and $v$ denotes an exiting positron. Taking the conjugate of this expression and using the trace to sum up over the spin states, the modulus squared of this expression can be found to be

$${|\mathcal{M}|^{\mu\nu}}^2 = Tr[(\gamma^{\alpha}p_{\alpha}+m)(A\gamma^{\mu}+B\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^5)(\gamma^{\beta}p_{\beta}-m)(A\gamma^{\nu}+B\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^5)].$$

The form of this expression is a second order tensor, which implies that the decay width will also be a second order tensor, which doesn't make sense. From what I have seen, typically these free indices contract against the lower free indices from force carrier production. However, in considering the Z production on the left of the graph, the graph would represent the cross section for some particles to annihilate and form a lepton pair, which would not describe the lifetime of the Z boson. This appears to mean that I've either made some very silly mistake in contracting indices, or that when examining the decay width of an object with a tensor propagator, you have to consider the particles tensor nature, or finally that examining the decay of a force carrier in this way is nonsense.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you missing a polarization four vector from the Feynman rule for the external boson leg?

Comment: I definitely am, thanks! That appears to fix everything.